# Bidirectional mapping does not pick up parent

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a bidirectional relationship between two entities. Here are the two classes, getters/setters omitted:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "strategy")
public class Strategy {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "strategy", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<StrategyDetail> details;
}
```

And

```
public class StrategyDetail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String content;

    @ManyToOne()
    private Strategy strategy;
 }
```

I then have a repository and controller over this, but nothing worth mentionning (my repository only extends the JpaRepository and the controller has a get/post mapping).

When I try to create a strategy, I send this JSON:

```
{
    "name": "my strat",
    "details": [{
        "content": "my content"
    }]
}
```

and the response is this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "my strat",
    "details": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "content": "my content",
            "strategy": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't get why the strategy is null here, the mapping is fairly obvious. When I then try to get the strategy, the answer is this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "my strat",
        "details": []
    }
]
```

Which I guess is working as intended (foreign key failure so the detail has not been saved?).

What should I change to make it work (meaning having access to the strategy inside the strategyDetail)? Even better I think would be having the strategy id rather than the whole strategy.

I've tried removing the bidirectionality by removing the strategy property in StrategyDetail and then it does properly save the details, but then I obviously don't have access to the strategy field inside the detail...

I've been looking for a solution on this for the past hour, looking at tutorials and what not, but I have not found a working solution.

Comment: Add `@JoinColumn(name = "strategy_id", nullable = false)` in `StrategyDetail` where `strategy_id` is the foreign key that references `Strategy.id` in your database

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Thank you. I've tried adding `@JoinColumn(name = "strategy_id", nullable = false)` to `StrategyDetail` but I get the error `NULL not allowed for column "STRATEGY_ID"`. It works the same as before, but now fails because NULL is not allowed. I don't get why it does not pick up the strategy id and tries to insert NULL. Here are the SQL commands executed by hibernate: `insert into strategy (id, name) values (?, ?)` and `insert into strategy_detail (id, content, strategy_id) values (?, ?, ?)`. I can't display the bound values, but the SQL looks fine to me...

Comment: Can you check your DB if the values strategy_detail.strategy_id and strategy.id are the same?